# Detecting if a specific cookie exist

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm working on a site that does have a lot of cookies already. Now what I want to do is do detect if the cookie named "login" exist. Here is my code:

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf("login") >= 0) {
    alert("login cookie exist");
}
else if(document.cookie.indexOf("login") < 0 ){
    alert("no login cookie");

}
else{

}
```

What is wrong with that code? The `indexOf` method will return -1 or 0, depending on if the cookie exist or not right? In both case its returning me -1 . Is my `if` statement wrong?

Comment: did you try to `alert(document.cookie.indexOf("login"));`?

Comment: Did you check that there's actually a cookie set? As well, since else clause is an exact inverse of the true clause, you can eliminate the `else if  {...}` and just go with `else {alert('no cookie');}`.

Comment: Read about javascript cookies: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Please don't link to W3Schools; see [W3Fools](http://w3fools.com/). [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) gives a much better page about cookies.

Comment: I forgot to mention that with my developer toolbar, I can see exactly all the cookie I have, and the login one is there, I tried to do
    alert(document.cookie.indexOf("login"));
but its giving me -1 when the cookie is there, and -1 when the cookie is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using jQuery the jQuery Cookie plugin. It make handling cookies super easy and painless.

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie